# Failed certification for Windows store app: Your app must respect user choices regarding the advertising ID

Tags: windows-store-apps, store, windows-store

I developed a windows 8 application, after submission to the store, I received the following certification error:

> Your app must respect user choices regarding the advertising ID

The fact is that I don't use any advertising SDK in my application.

what can be the problem here ?

Comment: Do you use Application Insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no advertising in your app, there can be misunderstanding in the review team. Contact Windows Store support and ask them about the real reason and what to do with this problem. They are very helpful. I had some problem with unrelated rejection before and they fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, that's what happened, we added a disclaimer and privacy policy sections and informed the review team that there is no Ads SDK used